# Is it good to use .fit to xtest when we use PolynomialFeatures() of sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, training, test

My teacher did this in class, and I'm wondering is this ok to use .fit_transform with xtest? It shouldn't just be poly.transform(xtest)

***Teacher's Code***

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
xtrain_poly = poly.fit_transform(xtrain)
xtest_poly = poly.fit_transform(xtest)
```

***As I think it should be:***

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
xtrain_poly = poly.fit_transform(xtrain)
xtest_poly = poly.transform(xtest)
```

As an optional question, what does fit() and transform() do in PolynomialFeatures? transform() scales the data based on some value(s) returned by fit(), such as when using sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler?

Comment: cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/71028410/10495893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically I don't think there is a difference in the output in the two methods, with the main reason being that fitting the `PolynomialFeatures` class to data does not save any parameters internally, as is the case for example for the `StandardScaler` class (see also [the source code for `PolynomialFeatures`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/preprocessing/_polynomial.py#L270)). However, I would say that it is still better to use `transform` instead of `fit_transform` to be consistent with other transformers from `scikit-learn`.